# Postgres remote connection

Tags: postgresql

Hello I have installed PostgresSQL 11 on CentOS Linux release `7.6.1810`.

I have edited files `pg_hba.conf`

```
host all all all md5
```

And `postgresql.conf`

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

However, following a restart I am unable to connect from pgAdmin with error:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is
>   the server running on host "10.190.9.130" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

If I run Docker container on the same server with postgres it connects successfully. Has anyone had this issue with a manual postgres install?

Comment: Are you running the postgres server inside a docker container? Then you must expose 5432 port. How do you start the test client? Please paste the command line.

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  Your local machine has IP address `10.190.9.130`?  And if you set up postgres via Docker container, you can connect pgAdmin to it successfully?  And if you set up postgres on your local machine (no Docker), you cannot connect pgAdmin to it?

Comment: Hi, I am using the following command to run the docker container: sudo docker run --name test -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxx -p -d 5432:5432 postgres

Comment: I have setup postgres on a remote server (10.190.9.130) and cannot connect from pgAdmin locally. If I run the docker postgres container on the remote server I am able to connect successfully from pgAdmin.